# How do I sort an array of strings containing times in the following format?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

```
durations = 
[{name: "test1", time: "2019-07-11T10:25:22.000036-07:00"},
{name: "test2", time: "2019-07-11T10:27:22.000036-07:00"},
{name: "test3", time: "2019-07-11T10:20:22.000036-07:00"}]
```

How can I sort the objects in this array by time.  I have a tried numerous times to get this sorted, but everything I try does not work.  Here is my latest attempt using lodash.  Also tried following the solutions posted here [Sort array by a date property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/sort-array-by-a-date-property)

```
orderedDurations: function () {
  return _.orderBy(durations, moment('time'))
```

Comment: I have tried with and without using moment

Comment: i just corrected them yea